# ASP NET Identity — как подключить в разрабатываемый проект?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Разрабатываю свой блог на ASP NET MVC, уже сделал кое какой функционал, в бд есть несколько таблиц:

- Статьи
- Категории
- Страницы

Для БД используется подход **Code First**

Сейчас делаю тщетные попытки прикрутить авторизацию.
Застрял вот на каком моменте.
У меня в VS заведено 2 проекта - Domain и WebUI. В каком правильнее реализовывать ASP NET Identity ?
И ещё вопрос. У меня уже есть свой контекст для подключения к БД

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
```

который наследуется от DbContext, а тут ещё надо создать AppIdentityDbContext, который должен наследоваться от IdentityDbContext<Т>

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
```

Вопрос - надо как то создавать два контекста, или это всё можно запихнуть в один? Базу данных конечно хочу использовать одну. Если можно, дайте примера.

Comment: У вас какая версия MVC ? В 5 версии уже есть ASP.NET Identity

Comment: да, 5-ая версия

Comment: Вроде бы, шаблон *Basic*. Там есть Identity + небольшой пример использования.

Answer (score 1):

[Создание приложения с ASP.NET Identity с нуля](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.15.php)

И далее читайте темы там ниже.

> В каком правильнее реализовывать ASP NET Identity ?

WebUI

> Вопрос - надо как то создавать два контекста, или это всё можно запихнуть в один?

Запихайте всё в AppIdentityDbContext . Добавьте туда всё что нужно из EFDbContext : DbContext

Или подключайтесь к одной бд двумя контекстами.

Comment: Т е получается, контекст подключения у меня так и будет в Domain, а всю логику помещаю в WebUI? Получается что команды инсталов Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core мне надо выполнять для двух проектов?

Comment: @Matsa, да, команды установки в двух проектах.